# Android Room Flow does not emit when last row in table is removed

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-flow

I noticed that a flow will not emit a value when the last value of a table is removed.

Example:

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM plants ORDER BY name")
    fun getPlants(): Flow<List<Plant>>
```

So there are 2 plants in this table to begin with. Now we delete plant 1. The observer of the flow is getting notified, as we expect. Now directly after that remove plant 2, the last plant in the table. This change is not emitted and observer will not get notified.

What I also noticed is that if you completely kill the app after plant 1 is removed, then start the app again and delete the second and last plant the change is emitted and the observer is notified.

Is this a bug in Room/Flow? I really do want to get my observers notified when this happens.

I'm using Kotlin 1.3.72, Coroutines 1.3.6 and Room 2.2.5

Answer (score 0):

I was just stupid. Apparently I cancelled the CoroutineScope somewhere, which was the same scope as the observer was launched in.